# VBA - use a sub or function

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code for a command button in VBA that uses a (column) range as input and has a (column) range as output. I want to use the same code for other command buttons that refer to other columns. I do not want to repeat the entire code, as only the reference to the columns changes.

I cannot figure out how to define this code as a function or sub that I can 'call' in the code for other command buttons which execute the code on columns B, C, D, etc.

This is the code. It removes duplicates and adds the string "rename" to each element of the list:

```
Private sub rename_column_A_Click()

    'copy values of sheet1 column A to active sheet
    Range("A1:A30").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A30").Value

    'remove duplicates, keeping first value as column header
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$30").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), _
    Header:=xlNo
    Range("A" & 2).Select

    'add string to each element of list
    For i = 2 To 30
        If Not Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "rename " & Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not declare your sub so that it takes a range parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like John Coleman suggests, you can have your Sub take a Range parameter:

```
Private Sub rename_column_A_Click()
    ProcessRange "A"
End Sub
Private Sub rename_column_B_Click()
    ProcessRange "B"
End Sub

Sub ProcessRange(ColAddress As String)
    'copy values of sheet1 column A to active sheet
    Range(ColAddress & "1:" & ColAddress & "30").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(ColAddress & "1:" & ColAddress & "30").Value

    'remove duplicates, keeping first value as column header
    ActiveSheet.Range("$" & ColAddress & ":$" & ColAddress & "$30").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo

    'add string to each element of list
    For i = 2 To 30
        If Not Range(ColAddress & i).Value = "" Then
            Range(ColAddress & i).Value = "rename " & Range(ColAddress & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I removed the two `Select` lines of code. I don't think you need them.

Comment: This worked out solution is incredibly helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi @Karen if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @ZwoRmi, got it. Thanks for the tip.